# How to enable json import in OpenSCAD?

Tags: openscad

I am trying to get the [catchnhole](https://github.com/mmalecki/catchnhole) library to work. Its github page mentions that json import has to be enabled, which is only available in nightly builds. I installed a nightly snapshot, but I cannot find any reference on how to enable json import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Edit` -> `Preferences` ->  `Features` -> ✓ `import-function`